# Help readers understand what "link-only answer" is in canned comments sent from Low Quality queue

Tags: feature-request, review, hyperlinks, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

[I noticed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaqCD.png) that the canned *link-only answer* message is currently plain text, while some other messages have links helping reader better understand used concepts.

- <sup>For example, current message for *not an answer* has links to SO FAQ and privileges page: "...once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)".</sup>

Please add a link to the respective MSE tag wiki, so that the message will be as below:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) can become invalid if the linked page changes.

---

For reference, current tag wiki text for the *link-only-answers* message is as follows:

> Answers which validity depends solely on the information available at some linked URL.
>
> Examples: ["this will help you"](http://www.example.com), "do as described [here](http://www.example.com)"
>
> See also:
>
> - [Stack Overflow FAQ -> Why are some questions or answers removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion)
>
>   > Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are … barely more than a link to an external site
> - [Stack Overflow -> How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)
>
>   > #### Provide context for links
>   >
>   > A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Perhaps the comment for a link-only answer should be entirely contained in an HTLM 'a' tag?

Comment: @Rosinante that probably would be fair... although not very nice