# Link to "your answer is in another castle" in the link-only comment

Tags: feature-request, link-only-answers, automatic-comments

Currently, the auto-text for a review comment for a link-only answer reads

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

I think that this might be improved by linking to [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), so that further education is reachable if the poster so wishes.

Proposed change:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. (See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370) for more information)

I just manually edited this into a [comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25777/can-a-judge-take-an-equal-bribe-from-both-sides/25778#comment133475_25778) on Mi Yodeya -- I'd love for this to happen automatically! :)

Comment: very closely related: [Help readers understand what “link-only answer” is in canned comments sent from Low Quality queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155980/165773)

Comment: This will become very ironic very quickly if "Your answer is in another castle" goes down, for whatever reason.

Comment: Is it an option to include that question in the faq? I just proposed this. Might help as delete prevention.

Comment: @PatrickHofman That would help.....I wasn't really worried about the question going down; though it would certainly be ironic ;-) .....I think that question does make sense as a [faq] question -- that's a great idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I partially agree with this; explaining in more detail about why link only answers are bad would be quite useful. However, the point of Shog's post is to address the issue of people flagging/deleting answers that are actually useful. There is an [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) answer [over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/238586) whose *sole purpose* is to explain why link-only answers are bad. I say we edit the canned comment to link to that answer (and make sure to clearly explain what that answer explains; having a link-only comment saying link-only answers are bad is hypocritical).

Comment: FWIW the part of [Shog's post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773) that I typically quote when flagging delete-worthy posts, seems to fit rather well doesn't it: "let me be clear: **this sort of response is *not* an answer**. If you see this, flag it. Moderators, if you see it flagged, *delete it*"

Comment: I think you're right; it makes a lot more sense to link to that answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I link to that post likely more than any other post on the network. I often include it for further reading for the questioner when answering *NAA* type questions on Meta.SO. I also link to it a lot in comments on the meta's. I consider it the **Official Post** when regarding when an answer is not an answer. So yes, I would definitely like to see Shog9's post linked in that auto-comment. It will not only help the answerers who leave link only comments, but reviewers will also be able to see that link and learn how to review in the Low Quality Posts queue better.

Comment: I don't link to it so often, but I certainly should. It says something important, and it says it well.

Comment: I [just linked to it](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25777/can-a-judge-take-an-equal-bribe-from-both-sides/25778#comment133475_25778)! In the VLQ queue, too! :P